# Dumping HTTP requests with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am developing a Flask application based web application ( https://github.com/opensourcehacker/sevabot ) which has HTTP based API services.

Many developers are using and extending the API and I'd like to add a feature which prints Flask's HTTP request to Python logging output, so you can see raw HTTP payloads, source IP and headers you get.

- What hooks Flask offers where this kind of HTTP request dumping would be the easiest to implement
- Are there any existing solutions and best practices to learn from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flask makes a standard [logger](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/logging.html#logging.Logger) available at at [`current_app.logger`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#logging), there's an example configuration in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3257877), though you can centralise the logging calls in a before_request handler if you want to log every request:

```
from flask import request, current_app

@app.before_request
def log_request():
    if current_app.config.get('LOG_REQUESTS'):
        current_app.logger.debug('whatever')
        # Or if you dont want to use a logger, implement
        # whatever system you prefer here
        # print request.headers
        # open(current_app.config['REQUEST_LOG_FILE'], 'w').write('...')
```

Comment: Initilialize with : logHandler = RotatingFileHandler(log_path, maxBytes=10000, backupCount=1)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] {%(pathname)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s - %(module)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s') 
    logHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    app.logger.addHandler(logHandler)
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) you can then call app.logger.info("message or string")